# Sublime text 3 autocomplete not working

Tags: python, autocomplete, sublimetext3

I have just installed Sublime text 3 on my Windows 7 machine to work with python.

I have installed a couple of packages via package control. The packages are SublimeJEDI and SublimeCodeIntel

I have tried to modify the configuration of SublimeJEDI adding this:

```
// additional python package path list
     "python_package_paths": ["C:/python27/Lib/site-packages"],
```

However, I am not being able to get the behaviour that I am expecting....what I am expecting is, for example, given this:

```
import numpy as np
```

If I write now: `np.` I would like to get a list with all of the suggestions from numpy package, but this is not happening

**EDIT**:

Seems like even getting rid of SublimeJEDI and SublimeCodeIntel, and installing Anaconda it is not working.

I am showing here my configuration file for python files (Python.sublime-settings), let me know if you see something wrong:

```
{

  "auto_indent": true,
  "auto_complete": true,
  "rulers": [79],
  "smart_indent": true,
  "tab_size": 4,
  "trim_automatic_white_space": true,
  "use_tab_stops": true,
  "word_wrap": true,
  "wrap_width": 80,

  "auto_complete_triggers": [{"selector": "source.python - string - comment - constant.numeric", "characters": "."}],
  "settings":
  {
    "extra_paths":
    [
      "C:/Python27/Lib"
    ],
    "python_interpreter": "C:/Python27/python.exe"
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that Sublime Text is a text editor not an IDE. Anyway, have you followed the [instructions of sublimeJed for Autocomplete on DOT](https://github.com/srusskih/SublimeJEDI#autocomplete-on-dot)?

Comment: Get rid of `SublimeJEDI` and `SublimeCodeIntel` and install [`Anaconda`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Anaconda) instead (completely unrelated to the Anaconda Python distribution). Edit the settings to point to your Python executable `"python_interpreter": "C:/Python27/python.exe"`, change anything else you like, and you're all set.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing what you need is to save the file with ".py" extension. If you see your code with colors, it's saved with some extension. After, If no suggestions yet, press ctrl+space, shif+space, I don't remember which of these is the right (my pc is turned off).

Lemme know if this solved your problem.

Comment: On Windows `Ctrl` + `SPACE` will do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are trying to save your anaconda preferences into the Python settings for Sublime Text, that is not gonna work. If you want to use the same configuration for all your Python projects, just put the configuration into the Anaconda's `User Settings`.

Anaconda is designed to use custom settings per-project so you can also add your related settings into your `<project_name>.sublime-project` file, anything that should be `global` must be configured in the global Anaconda (user) settings file.

Let me know if you need further assistance.

P.D: I just noticed this was asked long ago :(

Answer (score 0):

On Windows installs I believe you have to to use double backslashes for the python path to get it to work:

`"python_interpreter": "C:\\Python27\\python.exe"`